# Renaming MySQL Engine in MySQL Dump File

Tags: mysql, database

Here is the situation I am stuck in,

**Situation**

- We want to move from MyISAM to InnoDB Engine, so that there will be no table level locks.

**Catch**

- We can get max of 1 hour service downtime and not a minute more than that.
- Our DB Machine H/W spec is very low. 8 GB RAM.

**Learnings**

- Recently we learnt that, migrating our DB Engine would take 3 - 4 Hours, including DB Engine Conversion and Re-Indexing. (This was emulated with live DB Dump in offline environment).
- This is because DB Engine migration will re-create the schema with InnoDB as the Engine and re-enter all table data into new schema.

**What I found**

- One interesting fact I found is, after the MySQL Dump file is created, If I replace the text `MyISAM` with `InnoDB` in the Dump file and then import it into new DB, the max time taken was 50 Mins and all tables were converted to InnoDB along with right indexes.

**My Question**

- **Is the approach I took correct?**
- **Does it lead to any data corruption or index corruption?**

Comment: This would be more appropriately asked at http://dba.stackexchange.com, where you'll likely receive more specialist answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. No problem. Beware of the features which are only for MyISAM as multiple auto-increment columns, or fulltext indexing.